# Responsive design based on jQuery - changing elements, unwanted preloads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<img id="banner_desktop" src="http://hdwallpaper2013.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Space-Background-Images-HD-Wallpaper-1080x607.jpg" />
<img id="banner_phone" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQgcQd5s4R1KaQAQM6qJ3cUtEb2sdWjNGOOfzzdEt3mMx0TAGqZ" />
Site content Site content Site content Site content Site content Site content Site content Site content Site content Site content Site content Site content Site content Site content Site content Site content Site content Site content Site content Site content Site content Site content Site content Site content Site content Site content Site content Site content Site content Site content Site content Site content Site content Site content

#banner_desktop
{
    width: 100%;
}

#banner_phone
{
    width: 100%;
}

$( window ).resize(function() {
    if ($('body').width() < 300)
    {
        $('#banner_desktop').hide();
        $('#banner_phone').show();
    }
    else
    {
        $('#banner_desktop').show();
        $('#banner_phone').hide();
    }
});

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(window).trigger('resize');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j9jnq/

I have a "special" attitude toward responsive design this time. Here, the banner image changes according to the width.
But in this case, both image preloads, when youre on desktop, the 2nd image shouldnt need to load - on phones, the 1st one shouldnt. Its not only unnecceserly, it also disturbs a view, because something shows and disappears. But I cant do the showing-hiding before the HTML loads. I know there is mediaquery, but its impossible to do it for every elements (I will do this kind of approach with different sizes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either hide them both by CSS, and then when JS kicks in, decide which to show or, strongly suggested, is to revisit media queries. In the long run, you'll end up doing much more work and getting much less performance if you go with JS.

In fact, your code *right now* is harder to maintain, longer and less performing than a potential media query version doing the same thing.

Comment: but in this case, with a slow connection, nothing will happens for a short time. I see, but most of the time its not that simple to hide/show elements (reset paddings, change images, or even new HTML structures can appear)

Comment: But you need to do all the padding and all that in the JS too, right? An exception would be changing the src of images, but since you're using double images (like here) it won't matter. And about the slow connection, I think it's better for nothing to happen before we load **one** image, than to have glitches while loading **two** images... not to mention it will take at least as twice as long.

Comment: And for easy hide/show... You can simply add a class (like `small`) to all the elements that need to be shown in the small version, and have them appear with a single CSS rule. It depends on your approach, really, but I'd strongly suggest CSS over JS for this.